# PHP background process

Tags: php, background-process, bots

I've wrote a php irc bot, but i need it to work in the background. With this there'd be no quits or so. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the following website. There is a pretty descend explanation on how to write PHP daemons.

http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

Answer (score 2):

Run it in [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), then detach.  You can then quit the terminal and re-attach to the screen session later.

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar:

```
nohup php /path/to/script.php > /dev/null 2> /dev/null&
```